# send text file to printer using TCP not working

Tags: vb.net, printing

i am working on vb.net application,i used to print through com1 port my code is like this:

```
Using comPort As SerialPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM1")
     Dim fs As New IO.FileStream(AppPath & "\Print Files\TempBloodBag.zpl", IO.FileMode.Open)
     Dim br As New IO.BinaryReader(fs)
     Dim fileBytes() As Byte = br.ReadBytes(CInt(br.BaseStream.Length))
     br.Close()
     fs.Close()
     comPort.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)
End Using
```

but my new PC no com port..so i just tryed with below code..but not prinitng anything ..

```
Dim ipadress As String = "10.15.40.139"
Dim port As Integer = 9100
Dim client As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
client.Connect(ipadress, port)

'Write ZPL String to Connection
Dim fs As New IO.FileStream(AppPath & "\Print Files\TempBloodBag.zpl", IO.FileMode.Open)
Dim br As New IO.BinaryReader(fs)
Dim fileBytes() As Byte = br.ReadBytes(CInt(br.BaseStream.Length))
br.Close()
fs.Close()
Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream())

writer.Write(fileBytes)
writer.Flush()

'Close Connection
writer.Close()
client.Close()
```

Comment: re-write  `br.Close()` & `fs.Close()` after `writer.Flush()` and then run your code

Comment: @Nobody : That won't matter since he has already read everything into a byte array. -- @OP : Try `client.GetStream().Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)` instead of using the `StreamWriter`, and also have a look at [**`File.ReadAllBytes()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i just added like this : 
Dim PrinterLabel As New MyPrinter
 Dim Lines As String = File.ReadAllText(AppPath & "\Print Files\TempBloodBag1.txt")
        PrinterLabel.prt(Lines, strPrinter)

Comment: but my text file is very large,,its not printing